# Shell script Email bad formatting?

Tags: shell, unix, formatting

My script is perfectly fine and produce a file. The file is in plain text and is formatted like how (My expect results should look like this.) is formatted.  However when I try to send my file to my email the formatting is completly wrong.

The line of code I am using to send my email.

```
cat ReportEmail | mail -s 'Report' bob@aol.com
```

The result I am getting on my email.

```
 30129                 22.65        253
 96187                 72.32            294
109525                 82.35            295
 10235               7.7            105
  5906              4.44            106
 76096                 57.22            251
```

My expect results should look like this.

```
 30129                 22.65            253
 96187                 72.32            294
109525                 82.35            295
 10235                   7.7            105
  5906                  4.44            106
 76096                 57.22            251
```

Comment: Note the UUOC (Useless Use of Cat): it should be `mail -s 'Report' someone@example.com < ReportEmail`.

Answer (score 1):

Your source file achieves the column alignment by using a combination of tabs and spaces.  The width assigned to a tab, however, can vary from program to program.  Widths of 4, 5, or 8 spaces, for example, are common.  If you want consistent formatting in plain text from one viewer to the next, use only spaces.

As a workaround, you can expand the the tabs to spaces before passing the file to `mail` using the `expand` utility:

```
expand -t 8 ReportEmail.txt | mail -s 'Report' bob@aol.com
```

The option `-t 8` tells expand to treat tabs as 8 spaces wide.  Change the `8` to whatever number consistently makes the format in `ReportEmail.txt` work properly.